# multiple processing in WinCE6.0 or DMA implementation

Tags: c++, window, windows-ce

in my application i want to do the task parallely like one thread will do the calculation, and other will draw the data on screen, but while drawing the data processor is gettign engaged and during that time it is not able to process the data of diffrent thread. i runnig both thread on above normal priorty. Is there any way in whch i can do the drawing parallely, so that measurment thread can do the calculation at that speed wthout getting affected by drawing thread. i heared from some one DMA can solve the problem, but how to imlement it in WINCE6.0 platform i have no idea.

Pls provide any pointer

Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

No idea how DMA would "solve" this issue - you're using a single processor core, which can only execute one set of instructions at a time.  DMA won't change that.

The problem you're having sounds like you're using the processor at just about full capacity and so you're not seeing much time sharing between your threads.  There are generally 2 ways to approach this.

1) [adjust the priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885155.aspx) of your more important thread to have it get more time from the scheduler to do its work.

or

2) [adjust the thread quantum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885156.aspx) for your threads to force the scheduler to swap between threads more frequently.